# Can't install ASP.NET MVC3 RTM?

Tags: installation, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to upgrade from ASP.NET MVC3 RC to RTM?  I can't get past upgrading the vs10-kb2483190-x86.exe installer.  I get this error in the error log:
[image]
Do I need to uninstall the Windows Phone SDK first?  Should I hunt for GUIDs in the registry?

Comment: Do you have the Async CTP or something like that installed?

Comment: Nope, I specifically didn't install that so it wouldn't mess up mvc.

Comment: I had the same problem; I uninstalled Windows phone sdk, but it didn't help. There is a post from the guy that helped many people: http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2010/12/mvc-3-rc2-install-error-0x80070643.html - but I am still having the problem. Maybe you will be more lucky ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally gave up and reinstalled windows when I got a new CPU/Motherboard.  Took care of it, not that I suggest this solution for everyone.

Answer (score 12):

The installer appears to launch devenv.exe behind the scenes. I decided to launch VS2010 to see if it would "unlock" something. After it launched, I closed it and the installer started progressing.

Comment: Wow, that is so bizarre -- it worked. Thanks... Gotta love Microsoft. Idiots.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it did work - I just ran for the second time...

When you run .msp, it pops a prompt that "the network resource for Visual Studio installation files is not available". Once you update the location of vs_setup.msi everything else works fine. I didn't have to run MSIs in sequence as the post suggests - once location was correct, I just ran MVC3 installation executable, and everything got installed fine.

It looks like platform installer and MVC3 setup just fail and, worse, swallow the root cause problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It didn't work for me.  Running the msp didn't popup and ask me where Visual Studio is installed.  I think I may need to try uninstalling VS.NET. :(